# idle_in_transaction_session_timeout Parameter changing

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I should change the parameter "idle_in_transaction_session_timeout" in my RDS postgresql.

As I know with set command("SET idle_in_transaction_session_timeout=5s") I will change it only in session level. But I need to change it permanently on all databases. I can not find command to do so.

Comment: You need to modify this parameter in an RDS Parameter Group. If your instance is using the default Parameter Group, create a new one through the RDS Dashboard, as default groups are immutable. Once created or identified, modify the `idle_in_transaction_session_timeout` parameter within this group by setting your desired value (in milliseconds). After modifying the parameter, associate the RDS instance with the new or modified Parameter Group by selecting it under the instance's "Modify" option and applying the changes.

Comment: If immediate application is chosen, the instance will reboot, applying the changes across all databases. For changes scheduled during the next maintenance window, you can manually reboot the instance to apply them sooner. This will  ensure the `idle_in_transaction_session_timeout` setting is permanently set for the entire RDS instance, enhancing control over idle transactions as SET idle_in_transaction_session_timeout=5s wont work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After connecting to the server with the superuser user, you can proceed with the configuration as follows. This parameter does not require a restart.

```
postgres=# alter system set idle_in_transaction_session_timeout to '5s';                   
postgres=# select pg_reload_conf();
```

To pass this parameter specific to only one user, you can use it as follows.

```
postgres=# alter user username set idle_in_transaction_session_timeout to '5s';
```